# Creating temporary SwiftData object

Tags: swift, swift-data

I have a `Workout` SwiftData model and a list view of workouts. The user can create a new workout by clicking on a plus button in the toolbar of the list view, which is inside a `NavigationStack`. The `WorkoutsListView` uses the model context as such:
`@Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext`.

When I open the `NewWorkoutView` as a sheet, I want the user to be able to create a new workout and click 'Done' to save it (which will be reflected in the list view) or simply click the close button and discard everything. My question is, how can I do this with the SwiftData context? I have tried accessing the context in the same way as above in the sheet view, but the changes do not get reflected (even when I manually save using `modelContext.save()`. I have also tried passing in the container in the initialiser of the new view to create a context with this container and add the object to it; this also does not work. I would like to add that I have abstracted the context logic to the view models, i.e. I have a variable like this in my view models: `var modelContext: ModelContext? = nil` and I set it to the environment model context on view appear as follows: `viewModel.modelContext = modelContext`.

I have seen some approaches where the new object is created in the parent view and passed to the child view, but I would like to create the object ONlY if the user presses the 'Done' button in the child view, not beforehand. I have also tried to just create a variable in the view model of the child view and simply pass it back to the parent view using a call back method. However, this does not work as I am using the new `@Bindable` keyword in many of my custom subviews to bind to properties of the models. So when I use the approach I just mentioned, I get errors stating that the schema could not be found, which I assume is to do with the fact that the variable in this case is not a Model object that can be made `@Bindable`.

Comment: Without any real code it’s hard to know what is the best way forward but to mention two observations, if you create an instance of your model but without inserting it into a ModelContext it will be destroyed without being saved when the scope is exited and secondly if you want to work with a different context then you pass a ModelContainer to the sub view/view model etc and create a new ModelContext there  using the container.